# How to improve the efficiency of finding the most recent business day for all dates in an R dataframe?

Tags: r, performance, datetime, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a few million rows.  One column is a date column. I need to add a new column that has the previous business day.  I have a method to do this, but it is extremely slow.  For reasons that don't need to be explained here, I have to run this same transformation 5 times in a row.

I have tried to make a vectorized function that does the same as the above and then compiled it using cmpfun, but that didn't seem to speed things up.  I would really appreciate any thoughts as to 1) why this is slow and 2) how to do this more efficiently.

```r
library(timeDate)
library(dplyr)

# generate some random data
nrows <- 1000000
df <- tibble(row = sample(0:20, nrows, rep = TRUE),
             date = sample(seq(as.Date('2014/01/01'), as.Date('2019/03/31'), by="day"), rep = TRUE, nrows)
)

# get the holidays from 2014 until now
holidays <- holidayNYSE(seq(2014, year(today())))

# subtract a day from today, check if it is a business day; if not, repeat a few times
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    previous_biz_day = date - 1,
    previous_biz_day = if_else(!isBizday(as.timeDate(previous_biz_day), holidays), previous_biz_day - 1, previous_biz_day),
    previous_biz_day = if_else(!isBizday(as.timeDate(previous_biz_day), holidays), previous_biz_day - 1, previous_biz_day),
    previous_biz_day = if_else(!isBizday(as.timeDate(previous_biz_day), holidays), previous_biz_day - 1, previous_biz_day)
  )
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude only the dates in `holidays` or also all weekends (sat & sun)?

Comment: And what does "extremly slow" mean?

Comment: Thanks for both of your questions.  @docendodiscimus I mean to exclude weekends and holidays.  In terms of speed, it can easily take over 25 minutes for this to run on my full dataset (the function that runs this is called several times, so possibly 5-10 minutes each time).  The example above takes 20-30 seconds on my computer.

Comment: In your example, you have 1 million rows. If each row had a unique date, your time series would span 2739 years. Since you seem to work with NYSE data, I believe your actual time period of interest is _much_ shorter and hence most of the dates in your data are duplicated. Therefore, I suggest you create a table of all unique dates in your data, run your biz-day function and match the results back to your original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

In your example, you have 1 million rows. If each row had a unique date, your time series would span 2739 years. Since you seem to work with NYSE data, I believe your actual time period of interest is much shorter and hence most of the dates in your data are duplicated. Therefore, I suggest you create a table of all unique dates in your data, run your biz-day function and match the results back to your original data.

Here's the proof of concept:

```
library(timeDate)
library(dplyr)

# generate some random data
nrows <- 1000000
set.seed(888)
df <- tibble(row = sample(0:20, nrows, rep = TRUE),
             date = sample(seq(as.Date('2014/01/01'), as.Date('2019/03/31'), by="day"), rep = TRUE, nrows)
)

# get the holidays from 2014 until now
holidays <- holidayNYSE(seq(2014, year(Sys.Date())))


df2 = data.table::copy(df)


# subtract a day from today, check if it is a business day; if not, repeat a few times
system.time({
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(
      previous_biz_day = date - 1,
      previous_biz_day = if_else(!isBizday(as.timeDate(previous_biz_day), holidays), previous_biz_day - 1, previous_biz_day),
      previous_biz_day = if_else(!isBizday(as.timeDate(previous_biz_day), holidays), previous_biz_day - 1, previous_biz_day),
      previous_biz_day = if_else(!isBizday(as.timeDate(previous_biz_day), holidays), previous_biz_day - 1, previous_biz_day)
    )  
})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 19.828   0.906  20.789 


########## 

system.time({
  df2 <- df2 %>% 
    distinct(date) %>% 
    mutate(
      previous_biz_day = date - 1,
      previous_biz_day = if_else(!isBizday(as.timeDate(previous_biz_day), holidays), previous_biz_day - 1, previous_biz_day),
      previous_biz_day = if_else(!isBizday(as.timeDate(previous_biz_day), holidays), previous_biz_day - 1, previous_biz_day),
      previous_biz_day = if_else(!isBizday(as.timeDate(previous_biz_day), holidays), previous_biz_day - 1, previous_biz_day)
    )  %>% 
    right_join(df2, by = "date")
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.148   0.004   0.152 

########### compare results
all.equal(df, df2)
# [1] TRUE
```

The second approach took ~0.7% of OP's.

Comment: Holy cow!  This was both a very clever solution AND it worked like a charm.  The function that calls this now only takes about a minute to run on the full dataset.  Thank you.